# Django, Howto connect (and extent) facebook and django-userena or similar 

Tags: django, django-models, django-registration, django-facebook

It's been explicitly written in Django-facebook that they recommend it to be used with Userena:

> We recommend using Django Userena. It seems easier to work with than
>   Django Registration. Both are supported and good packages though. To
>   use django userena simply point to the userena compatability layer.

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'django_facebook.FacebookProfile'
```

My question comes from `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'django_facebook.FacebookProfile'` part. 
I have developed my own **UserProfile** in **Userena** and also inherited some system Actors like Student and Tutors based upon their own needs. so my setting is something like this:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.UserProfile'
```

Within the django-facebook there is also an awesome example project that has written for mixing userena and django-facebook settings. But my problem still exists..

Should I replace my own code with facebook's one ??

This is my code :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.db.models import permalink

from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile

from courses.models import Course

class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='user_profile')
    department     = models.ForeignKey('Department' , null = True , blank = True , related_name=_('user'))
    name           = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    birthday       = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(UserProfile):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course , null = True, blank = True, related_name = _('student'))
```

Thanks beforehand ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the fields required for Facebook to your existing profile.

class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile, FacebookProfileModel):
    ....

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Comment: Perfect ... yes, you are right .. and what about "AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE" ? Should it be set to django-facebook or userena ?

Comment: Yes keep it as it is. 
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.UserProfile' 

Cheers,
Thierry